# Laravel 5 Many to Many - Table name in singular

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

MySQL Tables:

```
- category
- unit
- category_unit (many to many)
    - category_id
    - unit_id
```

---

Laravel 5 Models:

```
<?php

class Unit extends Model
{
    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'unit';
}

class Category extends Model
{
    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'category';

    public function units()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany('App\Unit', 'category_unit'); // Table not in plural.
    }
}
```

---

Controller Code:

```
$category = Category::find($id);
var_dump($category->units);
```

---

Error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'database.category_units' doesn't exist (SQL: select `unit`.*, `category_units`.`category_unit_id` as `pivot_category_unit_id`, `category_units`.`unit_id` as `pivot_unit_id` from `unit` inner join `category_units` on `unit`.`id` = `category_units`.`unit_id` where `category_units`.`category_unit_id` = 1 and `category_units`.`category_unit_type` = App\Category)
```

Laravel 5 is trying to find the table `category_unit` as the plural `category_units`. As my database is not new and I already used it in production servers, I cannot change the table name.

How can I do to Laravel 5 use it with singular name?

Comment: Is there a need to use Polymorphic relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are trying to create Many to Many relationship using a polymorphic one.

The `morphToMany()` method doesn't take the table name as the second argument. I think your case is simpler, just change the relation to `belongsToMany()`

So your code should be

```
class Category extends Model
{
    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'category';

    public function units()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Unit', 'category_unit'); // Table not in plural.
    }
}
```